# how to hide action=http://www.example.com/products/scripts/tpd.php method=get

Tags: html

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="38%" id="AutoNumber1" background="bg.jpg" height="177">
  <tr>
  <FORM onkeydown=highlight(event) onkeyup=highlight(event)
onclick=highlight(event) name=f
action=http://www.example.com/products/scripts/tpd.php method=GET> ( How to This Link hide )
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="tpd12"/>
<DIV align=center>

    <td width="58%" height="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="42%" height="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="58%" height="15">
    <p align="right"><b><font color="#C0C0C0"><br>
    <br>
    <br>
    &nbsp;</font></b></td>
    <td width="42%" height="15"><b><font color="#C0C0C0"><br>
    <br>
    &nbsp;</font></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="58%" height="50">
    <p align="right"><font color="#C0C0C0"><b>Phone #</b></font></td>
    <td width="42%" height="50"><b><font color="#C0C0C0">&nbsp;</font></b>
    <input type="hidden" name="searchby" value="Phone"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="xyz"/>
    <input type="text" name="entry" size="12"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="58%" height="106">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="42%" height="106" valign="top">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Search" name="search"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Example Images

image code #1: www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1264733802.jpg

code preview result #2: www.koolfree.com/ImageUpload/uploads/1264722405.jpg

Plz help me how to set this script
thanks in advance

Comment: Just don't render the action attribute (as long as the page is posting to the same page).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes around the parameter values.

Change

```
<FORM onkeydown=highlight(event) onkeyup=highlight(event) onclick=highlight(event) name=f action=http://www.example.com/products/scripts/tpd.php method=GET>
```

To

```
<FORM onkeydown="highlight(event)" onkeyup="highlight(event)" onclick"highlight(event)" name="f" action="http://www.example.com/products/scripts/tpd.php" method="GET">
```

It would be simple to use an HTML [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) rather asking others for help.

Comment: Also, (s)he could try closing the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript (jquery comes to mind) to bind all kinds of events to almost any DOM element, and in my opinion it'll generate cleaner code to if you don't use the onclick, onkeydown, etc. calls in the HTML, but rather put all of that in a js file and just bind event handlers with functions to the FORM element.

Makes sense?